# Problem of multiple marker on same position in Google Map API

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using google map in my application. I have thousands of markers on my map.

I can display them well on map. I am using MySQL as my database in php.

But I have a problem when there are more than one location on the same position. It displays only one marker for all the locations(for same position).

In API, there is no solution for this. Can anyone help me for that ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a "problem" *per se*. Think about it... IF multiple points share the EXACT SAME geographic location, OBVIOUSLY, they're ALL going to be represented by a SINGLE point. What is really happening though, is that all markers for the same point are being stacked one on top of the other.

What you might want to try using is the MarkerClusterer to represent how many markers share the same geographic location as a cluster: 
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html

OTOH, if you have that many points sharing the SAME location to require clustering in the first place, it would be absolutely pointless to de-cluster them at the maximum zoom level. Besides, it's not something that markerclusterer will do.

If you do need a possible solution on how to represent multiple points at the same location individually, see my blog:
http://act28.blogspot.com/2011/05/multiple-locations-with-same-latlong.html

Answer (score 1):

For lat/lon *appearing* at the same place when zoomed out, but actually different, look at the clustering example at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Marker_Manager For *exactly* the same position, you can't do anything but change one's position slightly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are placing one marker directly on top of another. Are you using lat/long coordinates?  If so, you could adjust the duplicate locations by randomly adding or subtracting a (very) small value from the duplicate lat/long.  Kinda hacky, but i'm not sure how else you could handle this.

Comment: I don't want to change their positions.

Comment: Then I don't think you're going to have much luck, sorry.

Comment: I think I can do something like I can open a div tag with all the locations available on it with their link.

What do you think ???

Comment: Sure, you could link to locations like Yelp does.  When the user clicks a listing, focus on the marker and display the info overlay.  But it will look like there's just one marker there.

Comment: I think for that I can use a different icon and give users some information for that.

Comment: Ok I have done it. Soon I will place the url for that.
Waiting for my application to be live...

Answer (score 0):

What i did was hashing the long/lat values in a special array key. Then all markers would be in the same array key with the same location, you then can iterate the array and display the information in one information window.